# Saving Rx aggregates to a local variable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to gather statistics on a stream of `IObservable` latencies. In my case those streams come from the Tx driver for ETW trace files.

I have already written the windowed aggregates that give me those statistics every second, I'm having trouble with the "full trace" statistics which I would expect to return something when the stream receives OnComplete. Here is the code illustrating problem with that "full trace" statistics query.

The stream has 2 types of latencies which are easy to tell apart, anything > 10 is one type of latency, <10 is the other type.

```
struct Duration
{
    DateTime OccurenceTime;
    double Latency;
}

IObservable<Duration> observableDurations = ...

var statistics = 
    from duration in observableDurations
    group duration by duration.Latency > 10 into g
    select new
    {
        Type = g.Key ? "Latency Type A" : "Latency Type B",
        Min  = g.Min(o => o.Latency),
        Max  = g.Max(o => o.Latency),
        Avg  = g.Average(o => o.Latency),
    };
// statistics.Dump(); In LinqPad this shows correct results.

double maxLatencyTypeA = 0;
statistics.Subscribe(x =>
{
    if (x.Type == "Latency Type A")
    {
        maxLatencyTypeA = x.Max;
        // I would also save min and average into local variables
    }
    else
    {
        // I would also save the statistics for TypeB latencies into local variables
    }
});
```

This doesn't compile because in the definition of the statistics query, g.Min, g.Max and g.Average are `IObservable<double>`, yet in the lambda expression I pass to `statistics.Suscribe()` 
I try to save that g.Max to a `double` which obviously is not compatible with `IObservable<double>`.

I can work around this in the lambda by changing `maxLatencyTypeA = x.Max;` to `x.Max.Subscribe(s=>maxLatencyTypeA=s);`. My question is, is there a way to write a better statistics query that would yield types of `double` instead of `IObservable<double>` for the statistics such that I don't need to nest more subscriptions inside the statistics subscription for each statistic I might want to save?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using individual operators to aggregate individually, use `Aggregate` and collect all of your aggregations at once.  That way you can have a single observable that contains all of the results.  Note my algorithm for calculating Average here is subject to a little bit of drift due to floating point math.  If that's a problem, then you can also maintain a running Sum and use that along with Count to calculate the average.

```
var statistics = observableDurations
    .GroupBy(d => d.Latency > 10)
    .Select(g =>
    {
        var seed = new
        {
            Type = g.Key ? "A" : "B",
            Min = Double.MaxValue,
            Max = Double.MinValue,
            Average = 0.0,
            Count = 0
        };
        return g.Aggregate(seed, (total, duration) => new
        {
            Type = total.Type,
            Min = Math.Min(total.Min, duration.Latency),
            Max = Math.Max(total.Max, duration.Latency),
            Average = (total.Average * total.Count + duration.Latency) / (total.Count + 1),
            Count = total.Count + 1
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different ways:

*(Both untested)*

```
statistics.Select(a => 
     a.Min.Zip(a.Max, a.Avg, (min, max, avg) => new { a.Type, min, max, avg }))
          .Merge();
```

**OR**

```
statistics.Select(a => new
           {
             a.Type, 
             Min = a.Min.ToTask(),
             Max = a.Max.ToTask(),
             Avg = a.Avg.ToTask()
           })
           .Subscribe(async x =>
           {
             var min = await x.Min;
             var max = await x.Max;
             var avg = await x.Avg;
             ...
           });
```